# How is the sentence "This land is peaceful, its inhabitants kind" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, errors

This might seem like a weird question, but how is the sentence:

> **This land is peaceful, its inhabitants kind.**

grammatically correct?

Shouldn't it be "...its inhabitants **are** kind"?
The sentence is from a game called Dark Souls, it's from 2011, and it's very popular so I assume it's not a grammatical error, because if it's really an error it should've been fixed. So how is it correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? It's closely related, though with progressive constructions.  [Chekhov and the omission of "be" verbs with progressive tenses in compound sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529640/chekhov-and-the-omission-of-be-verbs-with-progressive-tenses-in-compound-sente). Your sentence is correct, though in a literary register ... even though the form of 'be' deleted differs from that in the main clause.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So the **is** after "This land" is a double duty for the omitted **are** after "inhabitants"?

Comment: You can consider it that way. English isn't perfectly behaved. You can look up 'gapping'.

Comment: My brother had been smoking ganja again. His hair was dishevelled, his clothes awry, his eyes glazed.

Comment: As noted, it's correct. Note that some stylists would require a comma in the gap: *This land is peaceful, its inhabitants, kind.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's parallelism or, in particular, [syllepsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_and_syllepsis).

It's somewhat artistic poetical figure of speech.

As to grammaticality, sure, people will look at you weird if you use it in speech. But if you're writing a novel then, sure, it's fine.

It's not a special rule of English. All languages allow this kind of parallelism. From Latin:

> Fur furem, lupus lupum cognoscit.

"It takes a thief to know a thief, a wolf another wolf."

Answer (score -2):

According to Ross, an acceptable sentence involving gapping is 4a' below:

> 4a)  I want to try to begin to write a novel and Mary wants to try to
> begin to write a play.
>
> .........................
>
> 4a') I want to try to begin to write a novel and Mary a play.

(Ross 1970 ) [[UCLA: Linguistics: Gapping](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/people/Kracht/courses/case_046_gapp.htm)]

So in the gapped (deleted) form, a different verb form (*wants*) from that in the first independent clause (*want*) ***is acceptably omitted***.

'This land is peaceful, its inhabitants kind.' is of a literary register. One would expect an expanded, more prosaic version to contain 'and' (or conceivably a semicolon) as well as 'are'.

A related though not identical example is analysed at [Chekhov and the omission of "be" verbs with progressive tenses in compound sentences.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529640/chekhov-and-the-omission-of-be-verbs-with-progressive-tenses-in-compound-sente).